# Prove or disprove a sentence using HPC

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

according to HPC:

Let S be a set of sentences and α that is not in S.
Prove or disprove :

> If $S\cup\{\alpha\} \vdash \beta$ and $S\cup\{\neg \alpha\} \vdash \beta$ then $S\vdash \beta$.

It seems like this is true, i tried to do some examples with a truth table and it always worked, i'm not sure how i can formaly prove this. Thanks in advance !

Edit : the Hilbert system i am refering to :
[image]

Comment: What is HPC and HPS? Those sounds like they might be one author's local names for particular proof systems, but they are not standard terms.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system

Comment: x @AmirH: There are many different Hilbert-type proof systems which differ significantly in (among other things) which logical axioms they have for handling negation. The proof you're seeking will depend critically on which _particular_ Hilbert-style system you want it to work for.

Comment: Note that your axiom (iii) is not very intuitive, and figuring out how to use it in a particular situation can be tricky. It will probably be worth your time to look through your text to see if it presents some other useful building blocks that can be proved _using_ (iii). For example, canned proofs of $\varphi\to\neg\neg \varphi$ and/or $(\neg\varphi\to\varphi)\to\varphi$ might be useful.

Comment: You can find a detailed proof into Geoffrey Hunter, [Metalogic : An Introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&pg=PA100) (1971), page 100, n*31.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have proved the *Deduction Theorem* for your Hilbert-style calculus, you know that the premises $S\cup\{\alpha\}\vdash\beta$ and $S\cup\{\neg\alpha\}\vdash\beta$ imply, respectively, $S\vdash \alpha\to\beta$ and $S\vdash\neg\alpha\to\beta$.

Now $(\alpha\to\beta)\to((\neg\alpha\to\beta)\to\beta)$ is a *classical propositional tautology*. You ought to have shown that your Hilbert-style calculus can prove all classical tautologies, and from that argument you can extract a formal proof of
$$\varnothing\vdash(\alpha\to\beta)\to((\neg\alpha\to\beta)\to\beta)$$
which of course also proves
$$S\vdash(\alpha\to\beta)\to((\neg\alpha\to\beta)\to\beta)$$
Now $S\vdash\beta$ is only two applications of Modus Ponens away!

Comment: I really like your answer and understood it completely, the thing is, we can only use the 3 axioms i've mentioned in the picture above, and Modus ponens of course. so i'm trying to avoid the step with (α→β)→((¬α→β)→β).

Comment: @AmirH: Unfortunately there's no real way around it. The only thing you can reasonably do with the $S\cup\{\alpha\}\vdash\beta$ is apply the deduction theorem and get $S\vdash \alpha\to\beta$, and similarly for the other premise. It may look less formidable if you think of you goal as $\{\alpha\to\beta, \,\neg\alpha\to\beta\}\vdash\beta$ -- if you manage to prove that, you can appeal to the deduction theorem twice to get the tautology you need. (Or just replace any appeal to one of those premises with the proof of $S\vdash(\neg)\alpha\to\beta$ you already know exists).

Comment: You're right, thank you very much !